# How to get value of byte that belongs to out of range?

Tags: java, casting

```
{double a = 295.04;
int b = 300;
 byte c = (byte) a;
 byte d = (byte) b;
 System.out.Println(c +" " + d);}
```

Storage size of byte is 8 bits and maximum positive byte value is 127.so c isn't equal to 300.Then I tried to convert 300  to binary number.The binary number(of 300) has 9 bits.I confused to get value of c and d .
why do I get c = 39 and  d = 44 ?

Comment: By "How can I get" do you mean "why do I get"? It doesn't help that you've posted code that wouldn't compile, suggesting that whatever code you've *really* got is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Byte is signed primitive datatype in java. When we assign something bigger than byte value, It is like a cycle.

Suppose you entered 300 in byte variable.
After first cycle byte variable filed with 0,127 means 128 place // 300-128 = 172

After second cycle byte variable filed with 0,127 means 128 place // 172-128 = 44

Now in the third cycle it is 44. I hope this will answer your query.

Answer (score 1):

You are rounding and overflowing here.

```
byte c = (byte) 295.04;
// will be rounded to 295 
// and then overflows +128 as 295 -> 39 (mod 256)

byte d = (byte) 300;
// overflows +128 as 300 -> 44  (mod 256)
```

Obviously, these are "lossy" conversions. Which is why Java will not let you do this without the explicit cast. When you do this cast, you are supposed to have considered what happens to values out of range.

Comment: yeah  overflows +128  as  295 but how do I  get 39

Comment: 295 does not fit into a byte. So it throws away everything except the low 8 bits, and that leaves 39.

Answer (score 0):

This code prints what you expect:

```
public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double a = 295.04;
        int b = 300;
        byte c = (byte) a;
        byte d = (byte) b;
        System.out.println(c + " " + d);
    }
}
```

You need to use `println` and not `Println`. The output I got in IntelliJ is: `39 44`.

Comment: What do you mean without using IDE? The code will output the same as it is not dependent on IDE.

Comment: @vimukthihett try to compile this code in cmd prompt, it will still show 39 44.

Comment: Well the op asked: `How can I get c = 39 and d = 44 ?` and it does that. I still cannot find any logical reason for a downvote?

Comment: The question was changed later on and for that reason this cannnot be downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

well ,try to understand the concept: the range of byte in java is 8 bits that means it can hold values upto(2^8) so when u write a value grater than 256(i.e, 2^8) what it does is that it takes its modulo with 256. Suppose if i want to convert 300 to byte the output would be 44(300%256).Similarly for any integer n the byte equivalent is (n%256).

Good day

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double a = 295.04;
    int b = 300;
    byte c = (byte) a;
    byte d = (byte) b;
    System.out.println(c + " " + d);
}
```

we use the (narrowing) typecasting here.The range of the byte is -128 to 127.so it is difficult to calculate.byte consist of cyle for its above range so the c=39 and d=44.